# How to convert list of raw data to list of Json?

Tags: c#, json

I have the following classes :

```
public class Solution
{

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public string CodeName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Createdate { get; set; }
    public string LastEditedBy { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string GoLive { get; set; }

    public virtual List<State> States { get; set; }

}


public class State
{
    public Solution Solution { get; set; }
    public string SolutionId { get; set; }
    public string StateId { get; set; }
    public string StateValue { get; set; }
}
```

Where StateValue is raw json string.

When I want to deserialise this I get a json string with \r\n .

Ho to tell the json serializer to not escape that string and treat it as json because it is already json.

I want an output like this :

```
[
{
    "id": "43c7f6d5-61dc-4c1c-8c76-e13878b7483f",
    "projectName": "Test Request 2",
    "codeName": "",
    "description": "",
    "author": "",
    "createdate": "02/13/2019",
    "lastEditedBy": "",
    "status": "Pending",
    "goLive": "02/13/2019",
    "states": [
        {
            "id": "cd7363f8-752b-4eb2-aaa2-ef94d7685153",
            "label": "Empty State",
            "layerone": [
                {
                    "StorageCloudPhysical_Custom3": "cc1",
                    "StorageCloudPhysical_WorkSpace": "ws for asset 2"
                },
                {

                    "StorageCloudPhysical_Custom3": "cc3",
                    "StorageCloudPhysical_WorkSpace": "ws for asset 4"
                }
       } 
     ]
   }
 ]
```

States in the json schema is the value of the operation Solution.States.Select(s => s.StateValue), which is something like List.

How can I achieve this please and thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include the code you're using to serialize the class object to JSON.

Comment: Plase add your serialization code. I recommend using json.net for this. Get Newtonsoft.Json-nugetpacket to start using it.

Comment: JsonConvert.SeralizeObject() from Newtonsoft Json.net will come to your rescue!

Comment: I have that statevalue stored as raw json in the database. I get as a string and I send it back to the front-end from my controller , but it is contains \r\n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED:**

What is your project type? Is it C# MVC?

First of all, you need to install the NewtonSoft library using Nuget, then, instantiate it on your controller.

[Newtonsoft](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

Now, you just "convert" your list, to a JsonList using serialize to do that.

```
var list = JsonConvert.SerializeObject<List<string>>(YorRawList).ToList();
```

Comment: I don't have a model, I have raw JSON as a string .

Comment: I have that state value stored as raw json in the database.

Comment: Then try to replace the Model for string.

Comment: This means deserializing it to serialize it later correctly. It works but it's a little bit dumb solution but I'll accept it.